# How to remove a label in <li> element and add image using tritium?

Tags: moovweb, tritium

How to remove a label in

element and add image to same using tritium 
how can i add a sprint image in place of that

element

```
<div id="TopMenu">
            <ul style="display:">
                <li style="display:" class="First"><a href="#" data-transition="slide" class="ui-link">My Account</a></li>
                <li style="display:" class="CartLink"><a href="#" data-transition="slide" class="ui-link">View Cart <span></span></a></li>

            </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: there is no label in your html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First in your snippet there is no label element...
But remove to any element use 'remove' function.

```
i.e. remove('label') //this will remove all label in scope

Now you also want to add sprite image.


 1. Just add your images in folder name as 'sprites'
         --path-- /assets/images/sprites
    2. Now it will include in sprites.png auto When Moovweb project run
    3. use class 'sprites-'+imagename where you want to place.
```